# visual studio conditional breakpoints throwing exceptions

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

I am trying to use conditional breakpoints to break when a certain value is set but visual studio keeps throwing an exception. This seems to happen for all different data types and different versions of visual studio (2017, 2019). I've installed all the latest updates for both versions and the issue still occurs. Does anyone know how to fix this issue (pictures below)?

[image: exception message]

[image: conditonal break point settings]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be that you need to switch to Managed Compatibility Mode. [This link explains how](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/10/16/switching-to-managed-compatibility-mode-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx)

Comment: that seems to do the trick, thanks for the quick reply!